Ionic React Axios / fetch() error? (plain CURL ok)
My test CURL (get) call works.
Problem: Same URL (used for CURL) inside my Ionic React app, iOS, (using Axios or fetch()) gives me an error.
--- This is the CURL which works
curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://www.website.com/filehandlingverifiedsession?seskey=0000000005711040000202405141237080003968400278187&id=94520' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/plain'

--- This is the valid result I get in Terminal, all ok

--- Now in my Ionic React app I am calling the exact URL with Axios but this produces an error.
const handleDownload = (documentID: string) => {
        console.log('ƒ handleDownload mxapp axios', documentID);
        var url = 'https://www.website.com/filehandlingverifiedsession'; //?seskey='+store.userSessionKey+'&id='+documentID;
        console.log('url', url);
        axios.get(url, {
            params: {
                seskey: store.userSessionKey,
                id: documentID,
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) { // from https://github.com/axios/axios?tab=readme-ov-file#handling-errors
            if (error.response) {
                // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
                // that falls out of the range of 2xx
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
                // The request was made but no response was received
                // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
                // http.ClientRequest in node.js
                console.log(error.request);
            } else {
                // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
            console.log(error.config);
        })
        .finally(function () {
            console.log('always');
            // always executed
        });
        return;
    }

--- I can see the following in the MacOS xCode Log (updated May15):


seems like you are missing a header value.

I have added headers (updated my code in my question) but I am getting the same error. The Server returns status 200.

Use console.error(error.toJSON()) to get a more comprehensive picture. See https://github.com/axios/axios?tab=readme-ov-file#handling-errors

@Phil I added headers merely because "user:StackoverBlows" suggested so (as first commentor)

@Phil I did add them in the CURL request because of copy paste. It works so I did not question it (probably copy-pasted from a PUT or POST ...)

Fair enough. Have you tried the error.toJSON() thing yet to get more information (3rd comment above)?

@Phil I have updated the code with error handling, ran xCode. The Log (in xCode) shows basically the same output (I posted a updated screenshot above)

That's not error.toJSON()

@Phil Yes, but logging 'error' or 'error.toJSON()' does not matter, it shows basically the same. Agreed?

As reference / followup for anyone having the same issue...
The problem ONLY became visible when using Safari and connecting the Dev-Tools to the iPhone Simulator in xCode.

And the following solved it. Documentation here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "capacitor://localhost"); // iOS
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost"); // Android
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET"); // , PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");


told ya..... ;)

@StackoverBlows no offense, but I doubt you were talking about the server side. If you were, your comment was anything but helpful...

You solved it by adding a header correct?  ;P If you wanted exactly which one you should've ask a better question better! -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
